# Using ZeroClipboard to Copy URL to Clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, zeroclipboard

I'm trying to utilize ZeroClipboard (http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/wiki/Instructions) to copy the current URL to the user's clipboard. I know I'm missing something here, but I am not getting any kind of error in the console, nor is it working as of yet:

JavaScript

```
<script src="/js/zero-clipboard.js"></script>
<script>
        var clip = null;
        ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath( '/ZeroClipboard10.swf' );
        function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
        function init() {
            clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
            clip.setHandCursor( true );

            clip.addEventListener('load', function (client) {
                debugstr("Flash movie loaded and ready.");
            });

            clip.addEventListener('mouseOver', function (client) {
            // update the text on mouse over
                clip.setText( $('#copyURL').href );
            });

            clip.addEventListener('complete', function (client, text) {
                debugstr("Copied text to clipboard: " + text );
            });

clip.glue( 'copyURL', 'copyURLContainer' );
        }

        function debugstr(msg) {
            var p = document.createElement('p');
            p.innerHTML = msg;
            $('d_debug').appendChild(p);
        }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="copyURLContainer">
    <a id="copyURL" href="javascript:window.location">COPY URL</a>
</div>
```

Any ideas what I'm missing in my code?

Edit: I also tried making the the clip.addEventListener set to window.location. That didn't work either. Could I pull the $('#copyURL') bit out?

```
clip.addEventListener('mouseOver', function (client) {
            // update the text on mouse over
                clip.setText( $('#copyURL').window.location );
            });
```

I still haven't figured this one out. Anyone have any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: Still haven't found a solution or where it's failing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out when setting clip.setText to window.location, it was passing an object. Had to start an empty string in order for it to pass properly. It's working now.

```
clip.addEventListener('mouseOver', function (client) {
            // update the text on mouse over
                clip.setText(""+window.location);
            });
```